# Deferrable partial unique index

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

My application has multiple users and an orderable list for each user. Items in the list can be soft-deleted. The schema is as follows.

```
create table list_item (
    id serial primary key
    user_id integer not null, -- Foreign key
    sort integer not null, -- The position in the list
    deleted_at timestamptz, -- Time of deletion, null if not deleted
    ...
)
```

`(user_id, sort)` must be unique since there can only be one item at each position in each list. To support soft-deletes, I exclude items with `deleted_at is null` from the index. So I have the following index:

```
create unique index on list_item (user_id, sort) where deleted_at is null;
```

Now, whenever a list item is created or deleted, I need to shift (increment/decrement) all the `sort` values. This may violate the unique index unless it is set to deferrable (or I use a less-efficient workaround to enforce update order). But a deferrable partial unique index is not possible.

How can I solve this? How should I change the design?

Comment: index is not constraint - I doubt Iyou can have a deferable index

Comment: btw why don't you want gaps in `sort`?..

Comment: `{` and `}` are not used in create table statements.

Comment: `row_id() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id) AS sort` will do exactly the same.